# Db knex migrations: KnexTimeoutError inside docker

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, containers, knex.js

After running `docker-compose up` which spins up two containers where one is an express server(listing) and the other the database(listing-db). Whenever I try to run the `knex migrate:latest` command in the express server (running container, after running the docker exec -it "container id"), I get the KnexTimeoutError. while I am able to get into the db(listing-db) container manually, and switch to the postgres user which is the superuser in this instance, I am not sure why connecting from another container (from the express server in this case) is throwing this error.

(docker-compose.yml)

```
version: "3"
services: 
    listings:
        build: "./listings"
        depends_on: 
            - listings-db
        environment: 
            - LISTING_DB_URI=postgres://root:password@listing-db/db
        volumes: 
            - ./listings:/opt/app

    listings-db:
        environment: 
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=db
        image: postgres
        ports: 
            - 0.0.0.0:5100:5432
```

(knexfile.js)

```
module.exports = {
     client: 'pg',
     connection: process.env.LISTING_DB_URI
};
```

(package.json)

```
{
  "name": "listings",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "db:migrate:latest": "knex migrate:latest",
    "db:migrate:rollback": "knex migrate:rollback",
    "watch": "babel-watch -L src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.28",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "objection": "^2.1.6",
    "objection-db-errors": "^1.1.2",
    "pg": "^8.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-watch": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Command run inside the listing container

```
yarn run db:migrate:latest
```

Error

```
KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/opt/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:349:26)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, typo `postgres://root:password@listing-db/db` >>> `postgres://root:password@listings-db/db`